# Eclipse ADT troubles with (image)button

Tags: android, eclipse, button, adt, imagebutton

I'm wondering what's wrong with my Android Development Tools. I can add a `Button` or `ImageButton` on layout, but later in my code I just can't add

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener) { ...
```

I've tried to test the buttons on my device but I got an exeption and my program terminates. And it doesn't matter if I add my own `ImageButton` or if I use predefined ADT buttons with default settings.

Any help is welcome!

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_unlocked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

ImageButton lock1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lock1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.drawable.btn_unlocked);

    lock1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    }); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post your logcat and which OnClickListener have you imported to your class?

Comment: Post your code and add Logcat !

Comment: Please edit the code into your question. It's impossible to help without the actual Java code and the exception details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to put a `Drawable` in your `ImageButton` variable. That's not the correct way as you might have already guessed by the name of the method: `findViewBy**Id**()`.

You'll need to pass Android the `ID` of your view so that it is able to retrieve it from the `xml` (Well, not from the xml, but you get the point). Altough you didn't post the logcat error output I would assume that your program died with a `NullPointerException`

That is because if `findViewById()` does not find a `View` for the given id it will return `null` as you can [read here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29). Your program will then die at the `.setOnClickListener()` line because you invoke a method call on a null object.

So to make a long story short: Edit this line:

```
lock1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.drawable.btn_unlocked);
```

to look like this:

```
lock1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```